# Why is event target the child if the event is bound to the parent?

Tags: javascript

A very simple situation:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="text">test</div>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
var item = document.querySelector('.item');
item.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  console.log(e.target);
})
```

I cannot seem to understand, why, if I have bound the event to the item, the event target shows up as the child and not the element I have originally bound it to?

I apologise if this is duplicate, I sincerely looked for similar question and answer beforehand, but did not find anything that would explain this.

Thanks.

Comment: Because a click on the child is also a click on the parent and events bubble up. The `target` property refers to the element that the event was activated on. `currentTarget` refers to the element the event handler was attached to.  If you change `target` to `currentTarget` you will get the parent element.

Comment: You did not bind the event to the parent, you bound the event *handler* to the parent. The event target is the child because because it is what you clicked.